# How to animate React Native FlatList sticky headers

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

here you can see nativebase.io sticky headers example: https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html

That works great, but i need to change sticky header height when it is in sticky position, so is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the `SectionList` of React-Native. It handles the sticky header and you have access to the props: `onViewableItemsChanged`. I used it to get the first section and do something with it (in your case, you could add an id the each section and save the state of the sticked section header.

Example of my usecase:

```
onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {
    const topSection = viewableItems.find(item => !!item.section && item.section.date);
    if (topSection) {
      this.updateSelectedDate(topSection.section.date);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          keyExtractor={item.id}
          onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <EventListItem event={item} />
          )}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) =>
              <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderText}>{I18n.l('date.formats.long_day_month_date_year', section.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}</Text>
              </View>
          }
          sections={this.assembleSections(this.props.events)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

In the renderSectionHeader you could change the header depending of the state

Hope it can helps!

Comment: onViewableItemsChanged solves my problem thanks bro!